# Error: HighlightDirective cannot be used as an entry component. NgUpgrade

Tags: angularjs, angular, ng-upgrade

I am upgrading my old AngularJS application to Angular using the NgUpgrade module.  Upgrading components seems to work ok but I have struggled with getting a directive to work.  After I couldnt upgrade my own component I copied the Highlight directive from the Angular tutorials and tried to use that instead.

So, I create the directive, add it to a directives module, then downgrade it for use within AngularJS.

When I do this I get an error:

> Error: No component factory found for HighlightDirective. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?

Ok Mr compiler, no worries, I'll add it to the `EntryComponents`. Refresh the page and...

> Uncaught Error: HighlightDirective cannot be used as an entry component.

Now I am stumped, how do you make this work?

**Highlight Directive**

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[highlight]'
})
export class HighlightDirective {
    constructor(el: ElementRef) {
        el.nativeElement.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
    }
}
```

**Usage in HTML**

```
<div highlight>
```

**Directives.Module**

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        MiscDirectivesModule
    ],
    entryComponents: [
        DashboardBoxSmallComponent, // Components work fine, directives do not
        HighlightDirective
    ],
    declarations: [
        DashboardBoxSmallComponent,
        HighlightDirective
    ],
    exports: [
        HighlightDirective
    ]
})
export class DirectivesModule {
    constructor() {
    }
}
```

**Directives.Module.AJS**
This is where my shiny Angular components are downgraded for AngularJS.
The funky downgrade code is from [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/16695#issuecomment-336456199) as apparently "Currently, you cannot downgrade attribute directives.".

```
const allowAttribute = directiveFactory => [
    '$injector',
    ($injector: angular.auto.IInjectorService) =>
        Object.assign($injector.invoke(directiveFactory), { restrict: 'EA' }),
];

const downgradeAttributeComponent = info => allowAttribute(downgradeComponent(info));

angular
  .module("app.directives", [...])
  .directive("highlight", downgradeAttributeComponent({ component: HighlightDirective }))
```

**App.Module**

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        UpgradeModule,
        ServicesModule,
        DirectivesModule, // This is the module shown above
        FiltersModule
    ],
    declarations: [],
    entryComponents: [],
    exports: []
})
export class AppModule {
    constructor(private upgrade: UpgradeModule) {
    }

    ngDoBootstrap() {
        this.upgrade.bootstrap(document.documentElement, [moduleName], { strictDi: true });
    }
}
```

Comment: I stumbled at the same issue, and it seems downgrading does not work on Attribute directives. I used a workaround I found at: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/16695#issuecomment-336456199

Comment: @BunyamiN Thanks, I actually found that and have a version of that code (`allowAttribute`) in my question but its still not working.  Have I missed something else?